# Spambot repeat part won't spam fast

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm working on a spambot but there is 1 problem I can't solve. I made buttons you can press, it says how much you want to spam. If you want to spam you will get a certain amount of time to go to the place where you want to spam. I made a function for how much the text will spam. But the problem is when it send 1 message it wait the certain amount of time time and not the 500 miliseconds

The script is written in C#. The target framework is: .NET Framework 4.6.1.

```
 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public void Time()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10;)
                { 
                    Stuur();
                    i++;
                }
            } // 10x
```

```
    public void Stuur() // does the sending
    {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    SendKeys.Send(textBox3.Text);
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }






    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Rush B", "5 sec voor spam",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Time();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // the credit
```

block
        {

`if (textBox6.Visible == true)
        {
            textBox6.Visible = false;
        } else {
            textBox6.Visible = true;
        }

    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}`

Comment: What is `textBox.Text4`? Where are you trying to repeat in your sample code?

Comment: textBox.Text4 is the box where you put in how many times you want to spam. What i tried was the function Stuur(); * textBox.Text4. But that doesn't work.

Comment: Convert the text from textBox4 to an int, then loop the Stuur method that many times when you hit button1.

Comment: Could you give me advise on doing it. I know this is the code to make it an int: int dab = int.Parse(textBox4.Text); . But I don't know where to place it and how to put it in a loop. Sorry for the noob questions. I'm new to c# programming.

Comment: It's good that you are coding at 14 y.o.  It is not so good that your first forays are to create a spambot.  Try a game instead.

Comment: Yeah I am not going to use it for bad things but I couldn't think about something else to create.

Comment: Please check the spelling of the `namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines?

```
    public void Stuur() // does the sending
    {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
          SendKeys.Send(textBox3.Text);
          SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i <= Int32.Parse(textBox.Text4); i++) {
            Stuur();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // the credit block
    {
        if (textBox6.Visible == true)
        {
            textBox6.Visible = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            textBox6.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

**edit:** closed parenthesis

Comment: I tried this:  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             
            for (int i = 0; i <= Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text); {
                Stuur();
                i++;
            }
        }.
but it says that a ) is expected.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to ya! I messed up and forgot the closing ) on that line. I hope you got it debugged!